# Is population standard deviation useful in the computers era?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Sample standard deviation used to approximate the **population standard deviation**. I can imagine this was very handy when you were dealing with a large population in pre-computer era.

Now thanks to computers one can calculate the **population standard deviation** quite easily. I am wondering is the population standard deviation still useful? Why?

Comment: You mean to say "is sample standard deviation" useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  calculate the population standard deviation if you had data on the whole population.  But in many cases of practical interest you don't.  All you have to work with is a sample.  Computers have not changed that fact.

Comment: Now that all data is gathered with computers one way or another you always have access to the whole data. Or is still there is situations that you do not have access to the whole data? Can you mention an example, please?

Comment: Does your computer know, e.g., the heights of all Australians?

Comment: Lol. Thank you Mr Israel for the answer and witty comment. I understand it well.